# files changes on host machine not mirrored on guest machine using vagrant/virtualbox

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I am currently following along with Semmy Purewal's book "Learning Web Application Development". At the current part of the book, I am learning how to use VirtualBox and vagrant to host a server on my own computer and then ssh into it. According to the book, any files in the vagrant directory of the host machine should also be mirrored on the guest machine in the home/vagrant directory, and vice versa. Until recently this was the case, and everything was working fine.

However, now when I try to edit files in my text editor on my host machine and save them, these changes are not reflected when I ssh into my guest machine. This is the case even after reconnecting, rebooting vagrant, and even rebooting my computer.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Sorry this is such a newbie question, but as you can tell from the book I'm reading, I am a newbie to all of this stuff. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Paul

EDIT: this is the output when I run `vagrant up`:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 3000 => 3000 (adapter 1)
default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version o
f
default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you
see
default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within t
he
default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed
on
default: your host and reload your VM.
default:
default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
default: VirtualBox Version: 4.3
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
default: /vagrant => C:/Users/paul/Projects/Chapter6
default: /home/vagrant/app => C:/Users/paul/Projects/Chapter6/app
default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks => C:/Users/paul/Projects
/Chapter6/cookbooks
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--
provision`
==> default: to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still
run.
```

This is exactly the result I wanted: the folder Chapter6 is mounted and shared on the host and guest. The only problem is that it is not actually synced... for example there is a file in /Chapter6 that is called "server.js" which I have updated recently, and if I `cat` on the host machine it shows the new version, while `cat` on the guest machine shows the old version. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The standard setup is to use Virtualbox's shared folder. By default it is mounted at /vagrant on the guest (assuming it's a *nix guest).

If there is no mounted /vagrant folder you should probably keep an eye on the output when starting your vm through `vagrant up`. It will output log messages when mounting the shared folder.

Comment: Jahaja, thank you for your comments. Yes, when I run `vagrant up` and then `vagrant ssh`, I end up in the "vagrant" directory on my host machine. Looking at the logs for `vagrant up` doesn't seem to reveal any problems, see my edits above for the relevant output. where can I look for the problem specifically?

Comment: Usually you don't end up in the /vagrant dir on login, rather you end up in the vagrant users home dir by default (/home/vagrant). You can see what dir you're currently in by the `pwd` command. To change to the shared folder dir - given that it works - you type `cd /vagrant`.

Comment: jahaja, not sure I follow... in both cases you mentioned I am in the vagrant directory no? if I want to lis the full directory where I end up, it is home/vagrant. Is this not the vagrant directory you originally mentioned?

Comment: No, `/home/vagrant` is the vagrant users home dir. the folder your looking should be located at `/vagrant`. `cd /vagrant` to change to it.

Comment: Ok I changed to it. What should I be looking for? I'm just not sure how this will help answer my question.

Comment: Going by the `vagrant up` output, if `/vagrant` exist you should be able to edit files in the `C:/Users/paul/Projects/Chapter6` dir on windows and it should be reflected in the `/vagrant` dir on the guest.

Comment: Jahaja, you were right, the /vagrant directory had the files correctly synced. I am now encountering other problems installing packages using npm in that directory. I am still confused about why the book says it should sync to home/vagrant and why that was working before but suddenly stopped working.